# Linq to SQL - how to dynamically filter by columns not in select

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

### The Problem

Using Link to SQL I would like to filter by columns that I do not want returned in the select statement.  This works fine as long as the query is built all at once.  In situations where I try and build the where clause dynamically, I get a compile time error because the column is not included in the select.

---

### Example

*WORKS*

```
Dim resultA = From logItem In dc.Log 
Where logItem.Message.Contains(searchText) 
Select logItem.LogID, logItem.DateLogged
```

*DOES NOT WORK*

```
Dim resultB = From logItem In dc.Log 
Select logItem.LogID, logItem.DateLogged

If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText)) Then 
    resultB = q.Where(Function(logItem) 
    logItem.Message.Contains(searchText))
End If
```

---

I am not sure not how to get round this.  Any help appreciated!

Comment: What's "q" in your second code block? Shouldn't that be resultB = resultB.Where(...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input Steven.  Your suggestion got me thinking, and my final solution was based on this.  However I found a way to reuse the same object by using a Lambda expression to specify a select at the end (in the same way as the where statements):

q = q.Select(Function(logItem) New Log With {.LogID = logItem.LogID, .DateLogged = logItem.DateLogged}

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do the select afterwards? I don't know Vb, but something like:

```
Dim resultA = From logItem in dc.Log Select logItem

If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText)) Then resultA = q.Where(Function(logItem) logItem.Message.Contains(searchText))

resultA = from logItem in resultA Select logItem.LogID, logItem.DateLogged
```

I think that will still generate useful SQL.

Comment: That's right. You first query return IQueryable(Of T) where T is an anonymous type that does *not* contain Message. That's where your optional Where fails. You can leave the Select for the end and you will get the result you want.

Comment: Although, you'll need a new variable to hold the Select results, since they will be a differente type than resultA.